# Simplification of boolean formulas without negation, just and/or

Tags: math, logic, boolean

I'd like to preprocess boolean formulas so that
  a and (a or b) and c

becomes just
  a and c

There are never any negations, so it should be a simple problem, but nothing really obvious comes to mind (other than folding and-in-and, or-in-or, duplicates, sorting). Am I missing something totally obvious perhaps?

Comment: What should (a and b) or (a and c) or (b and c) become?  Anything different from just that?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no simpler way to express majority(a,b,c) - it's a well known problem in circuit design.

Comment: a few answers already give you the Boolean simplification. You have not accepted an answer yet, and your comments make me think that we may not understand the question well?? Is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a related question on CSTheory.stackexchange, answered negatively [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/7467/5989).

The problem you are describing is coNP-hard. Thus, unless P=NP, you wont find an efficient algorithm to do that.

Converting to CNF or DNF will result in an exponential blow-up of some formulas.

Answer (score 1):

From your example it is not really clear what you want in general.

It seems you want to use the [absorption laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_law) to simplify the formula as much as possible:

```
A ∨ (A ∧ B) = A 

A ∧ (A ∨ B) = A
```

In your example you just need to apply the second absorption law once.

Answer (score 0):

A(A+B)C

AAC + ABC

AC + ABC

A1C + ABC

A(1+B)C

A(1)C

AC

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Will expansion reliably simplify it? It can obviously blow it up exponentially before figuring out it's duplicates everywhere, and there should be some way of taking advantage of lack of negations (otherwise it's NP-complete).

Answer (score 0):

Use a [K-map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).

Basically, you will create an in-memory graph of possible outcomes of the formula.  Parse it, and store it in such a way that given arbitrary input for all of the variables, you can get a result.  Then create an N-dimension array (where N is the number of variables) and try each combination, storing the result in the array.

Once this is done, follow the steps in the above article to come up with a simplified expression.

Note that this will work for expressions containing all types of boolean operators, including not.

Comment: Including NOT makes the problem NP-Complete by trivial reduction to SAT simplifying or not to false. I don't think this is the way, there is sometimes large number of terms in formula.

Comment: It is *a* way. K-maps have the ability to reduce arbitrarily complex boolean expressions to the most simple form possible.  So it will work for any input, assuming that you are able to compute the results fast enough for your purposes.  (Each additional variable should roughly double the amount of computational power required to produce the truth table.  For even a few hundred variables, this should take little time on today's processors.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider converting to [CNF](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) or [DNF](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form).

Simplifying the "bottom level" is easy -- just remove duplicates.  Simplifying the next level up is almost as easy -- remove subsets or supersets.